# Using UTF8 encoded string in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

I have a UTF-8 (utf8mb4) mysql database.
For some reasons, I'd like to use utf8 encoded strings in my queries. 
For instance, instead of using this query

```
Update mail_table set mail = 'john@foo.com'
```

I'd like to use:

`Update mail_table set mail  = SomeMySQLFunction('\x6A\x6F\x68\x6E\x40\x66\x6F\x6F\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D')`

How may i do this? Cast? Convert?

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: "\x6A..." is not "UTF-8 encoding". It's an *escape sequence* in string literals. Can you elaborate on those "some  reasons" and what language you'd need to generate those string literals in?

Comment: I use VBA (i.e Excel userforms) to interact (select,update) with my database. I use ODBC last version drivers. Everything goes well except with strings using arabic, chinese or exotic characters. I found a way to convert these kind of strings to escape sequences. Now, i'd like to use these escape sequences to update my database.

Comment: You likely have an [XY problem](http://XYproblem.info). I'm sure there's a perfectly fine way to use an ODBC database with non-ASCII data without resorting to such workarounds…

Comment: I didn't know what XY problem is. Nice concept! ^^ 
It's pretty much that indeed. But, I looked for a solution to X and can't find it so, i try to get one for Y. 
The issue isn't really ODBC database but datas that i got from VBA. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [UNHEX() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex).

```
UPDATE mail_table 
SET mail  = UNHEX('6A6F686E40666F6F2E636F6D')
```